# SQL 2-dimension query

Tags: php, mysql

I have been searching the Web and SO without finding an answer to a rather simple question. The thing may be that I don't know how to phrase it. Here is what I am trying to do.

I have a MySQL table with multiple SKUs (let's call it *skutable*) and for each line I have a certain number of columns describing the SKU : *name*, *price*, *price-range* (I have 4 different price-ranges), *week of publishing*, ... and a certain number of columns describing the performance of the SKU : *revenues*, *margin*, *quantitysold* ...

What I would like to do if writing an SQL query that allows me to display (with PHP) a table that would show for example :

*In line : weeks / In column : price-ranges / In the cell : the % of SKUs belonging to a certain price-range for a given week.*

or another example would be :

*In line : weeks / In column : price-ranges / In the cell : the % of qty sold for SKUs belonging to a certain price-range for a given week.*

I've been trying to write a query that would provide an array of multiple-arrays as a result but it doesn't seem to work.

If anyone knows how to do ?

thanks,

E.

Comment: What you're describing is a "pivot table". Unfortunately, mysql doesn't have this feature, some other databases do. But if you search for "mysql pivot", you can find some ways of writing queries to emulate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL query has to return one row (% of SKU, % of quantity sold) for each combination: week * price-range * another-dimension-if-needed. Then do your "tabular / cross tab" logic in PHP by looping through the results, or looping from min to max for each dimension and looking for the corresponding data in results.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. Thanks to your indications, I found the answer on http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#523 !